# Problema con consulta PostgreSQL compleja

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, sql

Por favor necesito ayuda con una consulta en PostgreSQL

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT("ventas"."Product Category") AS "Categoria de Producto",
(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "ventas"."Order Date")) AS "Mes",
"ventas"."region" AS "Región",
"ventas"."Customer Segment" AS "Segmento de Clientes",
COUNT (*) AS "Cantidad de Ventas"
FROM "ventas"
WHERE  
((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "ventas"."Order Date"))='4') 
AND
"ventas"."region"='West'
AND
"ventas"."Customer Segment"='Corporate'
GROUP BY
"ventas"."Product Category",
"ventas"."Order Date",
"ventas"."region",
"ventas"."Customer Segment"
ORDER BY
("ventas"."Product Category");
```

Esta consulta me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
Categoria de Producto|Mes|Region|Segmento de Clientes|Cantidad de Ventas
Furniture            |4  |West  |Corporate           |1
Furniture            |4  |West  |Corporate           |2
Office Supplies      |4  |West  |Corporate           |1
Office Supplies      |4  |West  |Corporate           |2
Office Supplies      |4  |West  |Corporate           |4
Technology           |4  |West  |Corporate           |1
```

El resultado que busco es el siguiente:

```
Categoria de Producto|Mes|Region|Segmento de Clientes|Cantidad de Ventas
Furniture            |4  |West  |Corporate           |3    
Office Supplies      |4  |West  |Corporate           |7    
Technology           |4  |West  |Corporate           |1
```

Yo pensaba que usando la keyword DISTINCT junto con "Product Category" iba a seleccionar todas las categorias de productos sin duplicar filas pero no es asi el resultado.

Comment: Una solución rápida es convertir esa query en una subquery y agruparla por los 4 primeros campos, usando SUM con el quinto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal es que, en tu `GROUP BY`, estás agrupando por fecha en vez de por mes.  Para corregir eso, simplemente reemplaza

```
"ventas"."Order Date",
```

...por:

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "ventas"."Order Date"),
```

También, puedes quitar el `DISTINCT` en el `SELECT`. No tiene sentido poner un `DISTINCT` si ya estás usando un `GROUP BY`.

Consulta corregida:

```
SELECT
"ventas"."Product Category" AS "Categoria de Producto", -- quita el DISTINCT
(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "ventas"."Order Date")) AS "Mes",
"ventas"."region" AS "Región",
"ventas"."Customer Segment" AS "Segmento de Clientes",
COUNT (*) AS "Cantidad de Ventas"
FROM "ventas"
WHERE  
((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "ventas"."Order Date"))='4') 
AND
"ventas"."region"='West'
AND
"ventas"."Customer Segment"='Corporate'
GROUP BY
"ventas"."Product Category",
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "ventas"."Order Date"), -- esta es la clave
"ventas"."region",
"ventas"."Customer Segment"
ORDER BY
("ventas"."Product Category");
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto!, como info adicional que podria complementar la respuesta, ¿Existe alguna funcion con la que pueda convertir el numero del mes a palabra?

Comment: Si, sería algo como `TO_CHAR("ventas"."Order Date", 'MONTH')`. Puedes encontrar todas las opciones aquí: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivovo esta subselect tiene que devolver lo que necesitas.

Tratas los datos obtenidos y sumas la columna `Cantidad de Ventas` sin agruparla.

```
SELECT
"Categoria de Producto",
"Mes",
"Región",
"Segmento de Clientes",
SUM("Cantidad de Ventas")
FROM

SELECT
DISTINCT("ventas"."Product Category") AS "Categoria de Producto",
(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "ventas"."Order Date")) AS "Mes",
"ventas"."region" AS "Región",
"ventas"."Customer Segment" AS "Segmento de Clientes",
COUNT (*) AS "Cantidad de Ventas"
FROM "ventas"
WHERE  
((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "ventas"."Order Date"))='4') 
AND
"ventas"."region"='West'
AND
"ventas"."Customer Segment"='Corporate'
GROUP BY
"ventas"."Product Category",
"ventas"."Order Date",
"ventas"."region",
"ventas"."Customer Segment"
ORDER BY
("ventas"."Product Category");

GROUP BY
"Categoria de Producto",
"Mes",
"Región",
"Segmento de Clientes"
```